# need help making website responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

everyone! I'm currently doing some free work for a friend of mine to contribute to my portfolio and keep me on my feet learning.

Everything is going great and looking great, but unfortunately, I'm having a lot of trouble trying to make some of the content responsive. I'm using the Bootstrap grid framework.

Alright so here's my CSS for the background which also needs to be responsive.

```css
.boxmain {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  max-width: 100%

}
```

That's a white box I've created as kind of like a sub-background that covers my main background image.

```css
}
.video {
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.underh {
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 33px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

That's the CSS for the content inside the box which is a paragraph and an embedded Facebook video.

```html
<div class="boxmain">
            <div class="container-fluid">
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                     <div class="video">
                     </div>
                     <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Feyeofthestormpro%2Fvideos%2F638067739703491%2F&show_text=0&width=560" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                     <p class="underh">Eye of the Storm Productions is an entertainment business dedicated to its involvement in the electronic music scene.
                        We offer a large range of services to  the underground electronic music scene and pride ourselves on the work that we do.
                        We offer our own selection of the best aspiring young DJs/Producers and photographers/cinematographers, as well as professionally run stage management solutions.
                        We have also partnered with Fulcrum Designs and Staging, to bring you the best in stage design and construction.  Including custom shade sail installation and VJ services.
                     </p>
                  </div>
               </div>
             </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         </div>
```

That's the HTML.
I would like to learn how to make this mobile friendly / responsive thank you!

Comment: it's not the full html right? and i bet this is your first post.

Comment: I only put in what was necessary?

Comment: first of all, i saw your code is bootstraped and it should be responsive. I think you missing something in html head or so the script.

Answer (score -1):

if you use % rather than px you will find the website will become more responsive

this may help: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_pxtoemconversion.asp

post more code will help*

Comment: Agreed. Percents are good, and depending on what way it's being unresponsive, @media rules are often useful. Check em out. Let us know in what way it's being unresponsive and we can give you more...

Comment: i answered with CSS rather than CSS3, I have not had much experience with @media rule